# Append text when html is dynamically generated with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have this html. I need to `.append` certain text based on some conditions:

1) `td.name a` contains `text which triggers append`

2) `td.name` and `td.quantity` are inside the same row

3) `.append` is done only in the same row `td.name` and `td.quantity` are in.

There are multiple rows. Rows don't have classes and code is dynamically generated - each row may end up on different position in the table. How do I target this

```js
if (jQuery('tbody tr td.name a:contains("text which triggers append")').length > 0) {
    jQuery('tbody tr td.quantity').append('<span>text to append</span>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="name"><a>text which triggers append</a></td>
        <td class="quantity">quantity</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name"><a>other text</a></td>
        <td class="quantity">other quantity</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery('tbody tr td.name a:contains("text which triggers append")').closest('tr').find('td.quantity').append('<span>text to append</span>');
```

```js
 jQuery('tbody tr td.name a:contains("text which triggers append")').closest('tr').find('td.quantity').append('<span>text to append</span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="name"><a>text which triggers append</a></td>
        <td class="quantity">quantity</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name"><a>other text</a></td>
        <td class="quantity">other quantity</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('table tbody tr').each(function(){
  $(this).find('td.name').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('a:contains("text which triggers append")').length > 0){
      $(this).siblings('td.quantity').append('<span>text to append</span>');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="name"><a>text which triggers append</a></td>
        <td class="quantity">quantity</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name"><a>other text</a></td>
        <td class="quantity">other quantity</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you have mentioned `td.name` & `td.quantity` are in same row, so I've used `jQuery` `siblings` to get the `td.quantity`.

Hope this will help you.